# In Perl : How to change the delimiter of a string ignoring those inside double quotes?

Tags: regex, string, perl, delimiter

I am new to perl and currently trying to solve one issue. Anyone who can help me would be greatly appreciated.
Input String is delimited by Space. I need to generate an output string with a different delimiter(say pipe '|')  but need to ignore the space inside the double quotes.

Example :

```
Input String :
Apple Mango "Banana/Tomato [, ANYTHING INSIDE QUOTE"  Grapes - "-" Pineapple - -
Desired Output String :
Apple|Mango|"Banana/Tomato [, ANYTHING INSIDE QUOTE"|Grapes|-|"-"|Pineapple|-|-
```

Note :

1. I  am aware of perl **quotewords** function but that is dead slow specially when we need to process millions of strings. Please let me know if there is any regular expression that can run faster in this scenario.
2. Double quote should not be removed. Need the output as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on delimiter change `'[ ]+'` (one or more spaces) to `' '` (only one space)

```
use Text::ParseWords;

local $" = "|";
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @f = quotewords('[ ]+', 1, $_);
    print "@f\n";
}

__DATA__
Apple Mango "Banana/Tomato [, ANYTHING INSIDE QUOTE"  Grapes - "-" Pineapple - -
```

output

```
Apple|Mango|"Banana/Tomato [, ANYTHING INSIDE QUOTE"|Grapes|-|"-"|Pineapple|-|-
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrote this a wile ago, it's a bit lengthy:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub splitOutput {
  my $sep = ' ';
  my $output = shift;

  my @token_array = ();

  while ($output) {
   if ((substr ($output, 0, 1) eq "\"") && ($output =~ m/\"([^"]*)\"$sep?/)) {
     push (@token_array, $1);
     $output =~ s/\"[^"]*\"$sep?//;
   }
   elsif ($output =~ m/([^"$sep]*)$sep?/) {
     push (@token_array, $1);
     $output =~ s/[^"$sep]*$sep?//;
   }
  }
  return @token_array;
}

my $string = <STDIN>;

my @token_array = splitOutput ($string);

print ("$string\n");
print (join ('|', @token_array),"\n");
```

This replaces the matched portion in the string in every iteration matching the next quoted or unquoted field. Note that if there are two blank spaces between the fields this will consider one field as empty. Also the result strings have quotes removed.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
s='Apple Mango "Banana/Tomato [, ANYTHING INSIDE QUOTE"  Grapes - "-" Pineapple - -'
perl -pe 's/ +(?=(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/|/g' <<< "$s"
Apple|Mango|"Banana/Tomato [, ANYTHING INSIDE QUOTE"|Grapes|-|"-"|Pineapple|-|-
```

This regex uses a lookahead to match 1 or more spaces only if there are followed by even number of quotes (to make sure space is outside quote) and replaces them by pipe. It is imperative that quotes are balanced.